# SVN: Authorization does not work on repository folders with spaces

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My SVN server is configured to run on Linux and I am unable to access the folders that contain a space in the name and the server always returns an `HTTP 403 Forbidden` error.

For example, I am unable to access the folder below:

> http://svn.prithvi.com/svn/repos/Project/branches/ADVID/Base lined Work products/Deployment/

Is there anything specific that I need to configure on the server?

Thanks & Regards,

Sudhakar

Note: I even tried the URL below and it doesn't work (replacing space with %20)

> http://svn.prithvi.com/svn/repos/Project/branches/ADVID/Base%20lined%20Work%20products/Deployment/

Comment: What versions of Subversion (client and server) and httpd?

Comment: Seems that domain has expired. Maybe that's your problem?